# how to rbind dataframes with identical column names in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rbind

I have a list like this:

```
list=list(
  df1=read.table(text = "a  b   c
11  14  20
                 17 15  12
                 6  19  17
                 ",header=T),

  df2=read.table(text = "a  b   c
6   19  12
                 9  7   19

                 ",header=T),
  df3=read.table(text = "a  d   f
12  20  15
                 12 10  8
                 7  8   7

                 ",header=T),
  df4=read.table(text = "g  f   e   z
5   12  11  5
16  17  20  16
19  9   11  20

                 ",header=T),
  df5=read.table(text = "g  f   e   z
15  13  9   18
                 12 12  17  16
                 15 9   12  11
                 15 20  19  15

                 ",header=T),
  df6=read.table(text = "a  d   f
11  7   16
                 11 12  11

                 ",header=T)
)
```

my list contains different dataframes. based on the column names there are 3 types of dataframe in the list.

```
type1:df1 and df2
type2:df3 and df6
type3:f4 and df5
```

I am going to `rbind` dataframes with identical column names and save the result in new list. for the example df1 with df2, df3 with df6, and df4 with df5 have identical column names.I need a code that automatically identify and `rbind` dataframes with identical column names.

the following list is expected as result:

```
> new list
$df1.df2
  a  b  c
1 11 14 20
2 17 15 12
3  6 19 17
4  6 19 12
5  9  7 19

$df3.df6
   a  d  f
1 12 20 15
2 12 10  8
3  7  8  7
4 11  7 16
5 11 12 11

$df4.df5
   g  f  e  z
1  5 12 11  5
2 16 17 20 16
3 19  9 11 20
4 15 13  9 18
5 12 12 17 16
6 15  9 12 11
7 15 20 19 15
```

the name of dataframe in new list could be anything.

Comment: ```dplyr::bind_rows(dfls)``` starting point

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(dfls)` rbind all dataframes together. i need to rbind identical 
 dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I don't like naming a variable `list`, I'm naming your data as `l`.

```r
lapply(
  split(l, sapply(l, function(a) paste(colnames(a), collapse = "_"))),
  dplyr::bind_rows)
# $a_b_c
#    a  b  c
# 1 11 14 20
# 2 17 15 12
# 3  6 19 17
# 4  6 19 12
# 5  9  7 19
# $a_d_f
#    a  d  f
# 1 12 20 15
# 2 12 10  8
# 3  7  8  7
# 4 11  7 16
# 5 11 12 11
# $g_f_e_z
#    g  f  e  z
# 1  5 12 11  5
# 2 16 17 20 16
# 3 19  9 11 20
# 4 15 13  9 18
# 5 12 12 17 16
# 6 15  9 12 11
# 7 15 20 19 15
```

I would generally prefer to use `by(data, INDICES, FUN)` to `lapply(split(data, INDICES), FUN)`, but for some reason it kept complaining ... so the above.

The choice to concatenate column names collapsing with `_` was arbitrary, intending to find a simple "hashing" of them; it's not hard to contrive a situation where this method finds two frames similar when they are not ... perhaps it's unlikely enough to not be a concern.

I should also note that I'm using `dplyr::bind_rows`, but nothing else from dplyr. This could easily be converted into something using `purrr::` or perhaps other tidy-package groupings.

Answer (score 2):

We can

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

bind_rows(dfls) %>% 
  mutate(code= apply(apply(., 2, function(x){
               ifelse(is.na(x), 1, 2)}), 1, paste, collapse="")) %>% 
  nest(.,-code, .key="code") %>% 
  mutate(filtered = map(code, janitor::remove_empty_cols)) %>% 
  pull(filtered) -> out

glimpse(out)

# List of 3
#  $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ a: int [1:5] 11 17 6 6 9
#   ..$ b: int [1:5] 14 15 19 19 7
#   ..$ c: int [1:5] 20 12 17 12 19
#  $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ a: int [1:5] 12 12 7 11 11
#   ..$ d: int [1:5] 20 10 8 7 12
#   ..$ f: int [1:5] 15 8 7 16 11
#  $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 7 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ f: int [1:7] 12 17 9 13 12 9 20
#   ..$ g: int [1:7] 5 16 19 15 12 15 15
#   ..$ e: int [1:7] 11 20 11 9 17 12 19
#   ..$ z: int [1:7] 5 16 20 18 16 11 15
```